# Convert GMT time to local time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, nstimezone

I got current GMT time - **2013-05-15 08:55 AM**

my current local time is - **2013-05-15 02:06 PM**
and time zone is - **Asia/Kolkata**

I tried to convert the above GMT to my local time with this code

```
   NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"Asia/Kolkata"];
   [dateFormatter setTimeZone:sourceTimeZone];


      // timeStamp - is the above GMT time

   NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeStamp];
    NSLog(@"local time is %@",dateFromString);
```

but this give me wron time as - **2013-05-14 19:04:00 +0000**   instead of **2013-05-14 02:06 PM**

Why this happens?
please help me to clear this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing is going wrong, a `NSDate` instance will never have a timezone ( well it will but it is always GMT, indicated by the `+0000` timezone in the date description).

What you are telling dateformatter in your code is that the timezone of the date you want to parse is `Asia/Kolkata` but you want it to be `GMT`.

First you need to make a `NSDate` object from the input date string with the time zone set to the correct time zone, `GMT` as you indicated.

```
NSTimeZone *gmtTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:sourceTimeZone];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeStamp];
NSLog(@"Input date as GMT: %@",dateFromString);
```

Then when you present the date as an string use :

```
NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Kolkata"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:sourceTimeZone];
NSString *dateRepresentation = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
NSLog(@"Date formated with local time zone: %@",dateRepresentation);
```

Comment: +1 but one minor nit pick.  I'm fairly sure NSLog always logs NSDates in GMT format, so the text `local time is` is confusing.

Answer (score 5):

The shortest way that I found to convert GMT time to your local timezone is

```
 NSDate* localDateTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMT] sinceDate:dateInGMT];
```

Furthermore, to convert this date value into string

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];//use the formatted as per your requirement. 

//Optionally for time zone converstions
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"..."]];

NSString *localTimeDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:localDateTime];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"local time is %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate: dateFromString]);
```

Comment: but here I am getting - 2013-05-15 00:59 AM 
My local time is  - 2013-05-15 02:29 PM

Answer (score 0):

```
NSTimeZone* gmtTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSTimeZone* localTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"Asia/Kolkata"];

NSDateFormatter *gmtDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[gmtDateFormatter setTimeZone:gmtTimeZone];

NSDate *date = [gmtDateFormatter dateFromString:timestamp];

NSDateFormatter *localDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[localDateFormatter setTimeZone:localTimeZone];

NSLog(@"local time is %@",[localDateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **timeZoneWithName**

```
NSDate *date=[[NSDate alloc]init];
NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Kolkata"]];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSString *dateStr=[timeFormat stringFromDate:date];
```