# iPhone issue with time zone

Tags: ios, iphone, timezone

In .plist file there's a field:

[image: plist]

I do read it in a simple dictionary.
Everything's okay, but on the client side, he says the time difference is -3 hours (i.e. he sees Dec 31, 2013, 10:30 PM)

I think, I should archive the project with his region settings, right?

**UPD**

- Date is stored in plist.
- The date: 1:30 AM -> this should the client see.
- Also, I use `NSDateFormatter` :

`self.customFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];`

`[self.customFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];`

then I convert to string using  `[self.customFormatter stringFromDate:date]`

And I think - I should look in .plist file and change the

```
<date>2014-01-01T01:30:00Z</date>
```

into

```
<date>2014-01-01T01:30:00-3</date> // I see Dec 2013, 10:30 PM; client sees Jan 2014, 1:30 AM
```

right?

Comment: One option is to persist UTC time and then convert to local time on view.  Or you can persist a separate timezone setting along with the UTC time and then display as <time> (<user locale>) with time being converted to the saved timezone

Comment: Agree with bryanmac. Save the time with UTC format and show it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for answers.
Let me see, I store time in plist, and read it once, and then store it in NSDate.
Due to this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/16560489/1040347 NSDate doesn't have timezone property

Comment: you never store a timezone so what do you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date is stored in the property list as GMT time.
Your timezone is "GMT+2", therefore "January 1, 2014 1:30:00 AM" is archived as

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>time</key>
    <date>2014-01-01T23:30:00Z</date>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So there is no problem with the plist *archive*, it is independent of any timezone/locale settings ("Z" = "Zulu time" = GMT).

It is only the property list *editor* in Xcode, which displays the date according
to your timezone and locale.

When you read the value into an `NSDate` object, it represents exactly this point of
time. To *present* the value to the user, you have to use a `NSDateFormatter`, which
converts the `NSDate` to an `NSString` representing this date/time according
to the user's time zone.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Yes, it has <date>2014-01-01T23:30:00Z</date> format.
But I don't get what do you want to tell.
Should I use `NSTimeZone` ?

Comment: @BraveS: Also "January 1, 2014 1:30:00 AM GMT+2" is the *same point in time* as "Dec 31, 2013, 10:30 PM GMT-1".

Comment: I should mentioned it before, but look, I have a formatter 
`self.customFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[self.customFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];`
then I convert to string using `[self.customFormatter stringFromDate:date]`
But I didn't help

Comment: @BraveS: What result do you expect? "January 1, 2014 1:30:00 AM" in your timezone *is the same time* as  "Dec 31, 2013, 10:30 PM" in your client's timezone. And note that the date format for 12hr time is "hh", not "HH". - Perhaps you can better explain what you are trying to do. Where does the date come from initially, how is it stored, etc ...

Comment: @BraveS: So you want to store "1:30 AM" in the property list, and all clients should see "1:30 AM", regardless of their timezone? - In that case you could just store a string instead of a date.

Comment: Martin, storing string in plist it's not properly. 
I want the client in one (-3GMT) timezone see one date, I instead see another

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44096/discussion-between-martin-r-and-braves)